# Why is my Oracle number being altered when filling my dataset using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll?

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, ado.net

For a specific example I have "31724977359034458496430204230" stored in the database but when I use dataadapter.Fill() into a datatable with a decimal column I'm getting "3172497735903445849643020435" instead.

I'm using the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll and I did not have this problem with the Microsoft provider.

I can provide the decompiled "GetDecimal" Oracle function if that would help anyone.

Note: this only appears to happen when the decimal is 29 digits in length.

**Edit**:  This same value is being retrieved correctly from a foreign key column in another table. Both are defined as Number(30,0)

Answer (score 0):

An Oracle NUMBER can have a maximum of **38 significant digits**. The .NET Framework decimal type is limited to **28 digits**. Reading an Oracle NUMBER into a .NET Framework decimal type causes an OverflowException for NUMBER values that exceed 28 digits. If you are reading an Oracle NUMBER value from an OracleDataReader, we recommend that you call the GetOracleNumber typed accessor method to return Oracle NUMBER values as an OracleNumber. If you are filling a DataSet, you can use the FillError event to determine whether an OverflowException has occurred, and to take appropriate action if so.

Comment: I'm not getting an OverflowException.  The decimal value is being retrieved correctly from other columns so I end up with a problem trying to match a foreign key (retrieved correctly) to my primary key (altered when retrieving)

Comment: I dont understand you, in your original post the value retrieved is incorrect, now you are saying it is being retrieved correctly for other columns... so the primary key is incorrect but the foreign key is not? So what is the difference between the keys on the database (check precision and scale). But note that .NET is limited to 28 digits for decimal datatype.  On the other hand I have never used the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll but the standard odp.net dll.

Comment: I edited my question with more detail.  Also, on the microsoft website it states: 28-29 significant digits for decimal.  It's stored correctly in the dataTable locally and pushed correctly into the database.